# Compare multiple input fields

Tags: jsf-2, input, primefaces, compare

I have following form:

[image]

I can add an answer with the add-button, so it is possible to create a question with more than two answers.

Also I have a pie chart of the results:

[image]

You can see my problem, do you? 
The piechart put my two answer options to one..

How can I check if one or more answers are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PieChartModel make use of a `LinkedHashMap` to store the chart data, where your answers are the keys and the votes the values, thus you cannot have the same answer-option multiple times in a piechart.

What you can do is e.g.

- use a HashMap in your ManagedBean to store thw answer-Options as well. This way the dubplicate answers will be ignored and only saved once, when you save your question
- check during the creation of a question if there are duplicate answers and throw a validation error
- ...

There are many ways to handle this, basicly depending on the exact behavior you want to implement.

---

See also:
[PieChartModel.java](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/model/chart/PieChartModel.java?r=4512)

Comment: I did not think about this handling. I am pretty sorry - I just want to validate it in my jsf. But this is a better and easier way. Thanks!